# What is meant by a function on a set.

Tags: functions

This question was probably asked many times, but i couldn't find by searching. And i figure that i'll get an answer faster then by searching.

We we say :

> functions on M

Does that mean that the function maps from $M$ to $M$, that it's image lies in $M$, or that it's arguments are in $M$ or is it very context dependent ?

Comment: My interpretation would be "functions where M is the domain (and every element of M is mapped)", but the codomain could be anything.

Comment: and the (codomain is the image space for you?) Meaning, $f : M \rightarrow ?$ Where $?$ means, we don't know where.

Comment: Yes, the codomain is where you have the `?`. It's sometimes called the `range`. The `image` of f would be a subset of the codomain, potentially the entire codomain

Comment: The domain is $M$. The codomain (where the values live) is context dependent.

Comment: No, codomain is the set mapped *into*. Like $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=x^2.$ This map is into $\mathbb R$ but not onto. Image is non negtive reals.

Comment: Thank you. I usually tend to write everything down formally as much as i can rather than rely on this type of terminology !

Comment: @barrycarter You mislead the OP when you say codomain sometimes called the range. Only for an onto function is the codomain also the range.

Comment: Depends on the context. In general set theory, this doesn't make much sense, all you know is that the domain is $M$. In real or complex analysis, and to some extent topology, it would likely mean *continuous* functions $M\to\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. In algebraic geometry, the range could be any field, but the function would have to be *regular* or *rational*.

Comment: @TomSharpe That's probably were my question stems from. Since quite often, it is clear from context what is meant. Seldom do the statements come out of the blue and without context, where terminology is the only thing you can rely on.

Comment: Should i close the question, or should i leave it here for other people ?

Comment: @barrycarter, you are free to write it as an anwser, if you like.

Comment: Some people use "function" to mean "function whose codomain is the reals", and reserve "mapping" for functions where the codomain is some other set. I don't like this at all, but I mention it because you may occasionally encounter it.

Comment: @JohnHughes Well, still better than physicists calling distributions functions.

Comment: @coffeemath https://byjus.com/maths/difference-between-codomain-and-range/ notes the 2nd definition of range as `It is totally ambiguous and can be used exactly as Codomain` showing that range *can* be used to mean codomain. I was taught to use codomain and image, and to avoid using range because it's ambiguous.

Comment: I don't believe in answers, but anyone is free to use what I wrote to create an answer.

Comment: @barrycarter Yes, on further looking I agree with you. It seems "codomain" is unambiguous, as is "image". It was only when teaching intro material from a specific text that I found "range" resticted to mean the image. But I do recall "range" being used in some older texts for the codomain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it means "functions with domain $M$, but the codomain could be anything."

Often, however, there's *context* established early in some document, as in, "When we speak of functions in this topology book, we always mean *continuous* functions." You need to be certain that you're aware of such context. And even the notion of *equality* of functions can be context-dependent -- sometimes analysts talk about functions being equal when they're equal almost-everywhere.

On a slightly-related note, the sets involved in defining a function have varying names used for them. When you write $f(x)$, the element $x$ is supposed to be in the *domain* of $f$; the resulting value, $f(x)$ is supposed to be in a set that gets called two different things: some folks call it the "range" (this was popular in the 1960s, when I was learning this stuff), others called it the *codomain*. If $f$ has domain $D$, we can form the set $S = \{f(x) \mid x \in D \}$. This, too, has two names. Some folks call it the "range", and others call it the *image*. Because of the name-clash with the other use of "range", it's probably a good idea to stick with "codomain" and "image" and leave "range" out of it.

For a decent description of what a function really *is*, consider looking at Halmos's *Naive Set Theory*. When I say "what it really is", I mean "a set theoretic object that has all the properties that we want a function to have, so that we can use it as our notion of a function." There may be other equally good notions of functions that are equivalent to the one in Halmos, of course. Once you have one workable one, you can just go with it, and pretty soon forget the details and just use the properties that you were trying to model.